# 3D Connexion-like device for Linux

Tags: linux, mice, ubuntu

I'm looking for a device to be used in 3D CAD, like the well-known [3D Connexion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079V4PXYD), that works flawlessly under Ubuntu 22.04. Even if it's a compatible one (like a cheap clone). I'm not a professional and it's just for hobby projects.

Comment: If the 3D Connexion one works flawlessly under Ubuntu 22.04, why is that device not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Romen because it's expensive. Perhaps there are cheaper, but reliable, products

Comment: @Romen the sentence "that works flawlessly under Ubuntu 22.04" is related to the alternative product. The original one DOES NOT work under Linux: https://3dconnexion.com/uk/supported-operating-systems/

Comment: OK, I see how that sentence could be read differently. I think your placement of the comma has left room for interpretation. Although there is actually Linux support for the 3D Connexion mouse [in certain applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/3D_Mouse).